# Войти в аккаунт юзера Python - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я бы хотел зайти в аккаунт пользователя дискорд через Python скрипт.

Возможно ли это вообще?

Попытался сделать это:

```
import discord
from discord.ext
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
bot.run("_Token_", bot=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селф боты запрещены правилами Discord, поэтому в последних версиях discord.py эту функцию отключили, лучше делайте через api discord(запросами)

```
import requests

def get_data():
    headers = {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'Authorization': "токен пользователя" # если бот, то "Bot 'token'"
    }
    response = requests.get(url='https://discord.com/api/users/@me', headers=headers, timeout=5)
    return response.json()

def main():
    get_data():

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо.

Comment: Если это помогло, отметьте этот ответ как решение, нажав галочку слева